# Are there safeguards to protect retail forex traders against forex dealers' conflicts of interest?

Tags: trading, foreign-exchange

I have noticed that firms catering to retail forex trading are essentially dealers with a captive audience: their clients. These forex dealers get to set any price they want because they are the only dealer available to their clients. When retail traders want to sell at a high price, the forex dealer wants to buy from them at a low price. When retail traders want to buy at a low price, the forex dealer wants to sell to them at a high price. Retail traders rely on forex dealers to get the best price, but the best price for the forex trader is a bad price for the forex dealer.

I am not familiar with the forex market, but it seems that the situation looks grim for the forex trader. They are always trading against a single dealer who gets to control the price, who gets to see all limit orders and stop orders, and who benefits when their clients do not get the best price. This looks terribly rigged. Am I correct in my grim assessment of the retail forex trading? Are there safeguards similar to those of the stock market to protect the retail forex trader?

(If answers are country-specific, please answer about the US.)

Comment: Why do you think they are constrained to a single dealer?

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica If you make an account at OANDA, OANDA is your dealer; they set the bid and ask. If you make an account at FXCM, FXCM is your dealer; they set the bid and ask.

Comment: What stops you making two or more accounts? I guess once you've got a position with one you might only be able to sell it there, but you could still use the another broker for your next position, etc.

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica Even if I do so, I still cannot be assured of "best execution" because these forex firms are dealers. Broker-dealers look out for their own interests, and these interests seem to be in direct conflict with the interests of the retail forex trader.

Comment: Sure, but how is this any different to e.g. a supermarket? The supermarket wants to charge as much as possible but doesn't because of competition. The premise of your question is based on clients being "captive" but I don't see how that's the case.

Comment: Not familiar with US Forex dealers - can you transfer out your assets without first converting them back to USD? Basically, can you just take your EUR and switch to another dealer which offers a better price? If not, then what you invested in aren't really EUR.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT. I must be missing my glasses, NO idea how I found a post ages ago.
If reply is not needed, I will delete it.

Yes, that is how it is, dealers are after all brokers and this is the retail market. Retail best defense has always been education.
Please do however, bear in mind, this is the market access into forex market WITH leverage, and what used to be a very big boys area. (ie, you would need a pretty big account in order to trade. Now people could "trade" with pretty much $100 or so)

First cut will be the spread you pay (marked up of course, after what the broker paid for it) and second, depending on the sort of account you are in, you get the commission. At some times, there is also slippage and post trade mark up...

In times of market volatility, spreads are naturally widen but that is mostly reflective of the markets and underlying liquidity providers (LP). Here is the interesting part, when spreads widen, it MAY not be your broker widening you, but the underlying LP doing so.

Most retail dealers(brokerage) works on A - B book strategy and this will also be reflective of the spread and charges. (for more information please google..) So most of the retail orders will be matched off by itself anyway(mostly the orders are too small to send out as they might be costly, or they would prefer to aggregate them, etc etc), making it a very profitable business as good statistic of retail accounts go to '0' quite quick(without ever seeing the market) due to the nature risk of the business.

I find the entire concept of trading very similar to gambling but is glorified as "trading". But it is what is is, just another business to some.

Long story short, yes that is the price paid for market access into the forex markets. Not all markets are the same and some are higher value than others, ie NDFs which is amazing how much a retail trader can get his or her hands on these days..

Comment: The question asked about **safeguards** to protect retail forex traders.  I've read this answer a couple of times, and the only thing close to a safeguard that I can see mentioned is "education" - meaning, presumably, that the retail trader should be *cautious*.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, and I am not saying buy a course or attend one of those "sure win" workshop. I do not think that is needed, as free resource are aplenty these days. There are no magic bullets, just understanding the risk involved, and stomaching it. Because at every turn and every chance, like in the wild, everything wants a piece of "it".